# TemplateProcessor error 500 on the serveur but not locally

Tags: phpword

I have a problem with phpWord and TemplateProcessor. 
I do a very simple example :

```
require '../../vendor/autoload.php';

$document = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('test/test2.docx');

$document->setValue('test',1);


$document->saveAs('test2.docx');
header("location:test2.docx");
```

When I run it on my laptop, everything is fine, but on the server, nothing happens, I get error 500.

(For inf : I use Spreadsheet for excel, and all is OK localhost and serveur.)

```
PhpWord version is 0.16 with composer
Php 7.3
Localhost : windows.
Serveur: linux with for the directory chmod 0755
```

When I do a

```
echo sys_get_temp_dir() . PHP_EOL;
```

I get : /tmp.

And one last thing, if I use

```
$PHPWord->loadTemplate,
```

it's fine on the server, but loadTemplate doesn't have the cloneBlock function.

If someone could help me, it would be very friendly, I've lost all my hair.

Thierry

Comment: You could check your `error.log` file on your server to determine if PHP threw an error on some function or exension. You can also add `ini_set("display_errors", 1);` to the start of your script to show errors instead of 500 codes.

Comment: first thank for your help.

Comment: I write : ````ini_set("display_errors", 1);

require '../../vendor/autoload.php';

$document = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('test/test2.docx');

$document->setValue('test',1);


$document->saveAs('test2.docx');
header("location:test2.docx"); ```` but I have no response by the serveur

Comment: Okay, I figured, I was pretty sure it was a problem with the temp file. I contacted my web host who changed the rights and now everything is fine.
Here's for those of you who might have the same problem.
With the old loadTemplate version it was not handled the same way.